# Can a photo taken from iOS safari input file be saved to camera roll?

Tags: ios, html, image, safari, mobile-safari

Using an input tag like so in iOS and clicking on it would display this menu:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

[image: Take photo iOS]

If the user clicks on Take Photo, then take a photo, it is not saved to his Camera Roll.  Is there any way to enable that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would not assume that to be possible. Why would you want this behaviour?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is asking how to use one specific web browser on specific platform (Safari on iOS) which has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I was searching for an attribute to set in the <input /> in html that safari might be able to use to enable this behavior.  I was not asking about settings in iOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an option to download the taken photo afterwords...

Sorry, I can't comment, too less reputation points...